# For which joint distributions is a conditional expectation an additive function?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I know that, for a random vector $(X,Y,Z)$ jointly normally distributed, the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\,X\mid Y=y,Z=z]$ is an additive function of $y$ and $z$.

For what other distributions is this true?

Comment: By "additive" you really mean "linear", perhaps?

Comment: Yes. I mean that the "doubly-conditional expectation" can be written as a sum of "singly-conditional" expectations on y and z

Comment: That's not the same thing. Suppose that  $E(X|Y,Z)=a E(Y)^2 +b \log( E(Z))$

Comment: True. I only need that it is separable (additively decomposed)

Comment: My previous comment is wrong (the expectations on the RHS  should go); anyway, I guess you want: $E(X|Y,Z)=g(Y)+h(Z)$. I doubt you'll get some useful characterization of this.

Comment: Thanks, yes. Hm… Would you know of a characterisation for the (stronger) linear case?